# Get row numbers where string is not empty

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array which has 4 columns and approx. 2000 rows. In the second column there are some string values. I need to get the row numbers of these values where there is some text. All I can seem to do is get a logical vector returned which is not really what I am after.

```
ID      New ID
123
956
987     655
321     656
987    
144     329
```

So I would like a vector that would return the row numbers [3,4,6].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert logical index to numerical index by `find`.

```
index = find(~cellfun(@isempty, array(:, 2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find the rows that have some text(strings) in the second column, you may use [**`ischar`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html) and check against all second column entries.

**Code**

```
%%// Create some random cell array for demo
cell_array1 = cell(4,2);
cell_array1(:,1) = {34,45,22,12};
cell_array1(:,2) = {'hmm',45,'say',12}

%%// Required row indices 
ind = find(cellfun(@ischar, cell_array1(:, 2)))
```

**Output**

```
cell_array1 = 

    [34]    'hmm'
    [45]    [ 45]
    [22]    'say'
    [12]    [ 12]


ind =

     1
     3
```